# Copy specific columns in CSV file and write it in new CSV file using Java

Tags: java, arrays, csv, file, opencsv

I have a predefined headers in a String[] and I want to compare it with the CSV file (demo.csv) which have headers in first row and values next rows.

**Eg :**
**Demo.csv**

[image]

**String[] =** [Name, Age, Location, Phone]

The headers in the demo.csv file are interchanged compared to String[]. So, here I need to compare demo.csv file headers with String[]. If both are in the same order, then we don't need to create a new file.

If it is interchanged then we need to create a new csv file with predefined format with the corresponding values in demo.csv file

Using the below code, I have created a new file

```
public String createNewFile(String uploadFileName) throws IOException {
    String fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(uploadFileName);
    File newFile = new File("fileName.csv");
    if(newFile.exists())
        newFile.delete();

    newFile.createNewFile();

    return newFile.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Using the below code, I tried to write it in separate file. But it is writing exact data in the demo.csv file without comparing

```
public void reArrange(String inputFileNameHeader, String uploadFileName, String newFilePath) throws IOException {
    String newFile = createNewFile(newFilePath, uploadFileName);
    
    CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(newFile), CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR, CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER);
    String[] fileHeaderInPropFile = inputFileNameHeader.split(",");
    
    CSVReader uploadFileReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(uploadFileName));
    String[] uploadFileHeaders = uploadFileReader.readNext();
    
    for (String header : fileHeaderInPropFile) {
        for (int i = 0; i < uploadFileHeaders.length; i++) {
            if (header.contains(uploadFileHeaders[i])) {
                File file = new File(uploadFileName); 
                List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8); 
                
                for (String line1 : lines) { 
                   String[] array = line1.split(","); 
                   writer.writeNext(array);
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    writer.close();
}
```

So, here I want to write the headers along with values present in demo.csv file in the new file.

**Output File should be like below**

[image]

Comment: can you provide what `output` you're getting for your program? didn't get "it is writing exact data in the demo.csv file without comparing"!

Comment: Yes. It writing the result as similar to demo.csv. Because of  List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you should create a new file with fix columns if the uploaded csv's header is in different order.
I think OpenCSV do it for you. This code is working for me with your example excel and produces fix column output.

Simple Pojo model for manipulating on it

```
public class Person {

@CsvBindByName(column = "Name", required = true)
private String name;
@CsvBindByName(column = "Age", required = true)
private int age;
@CsvBindByName(column = "Location", required = true)
private String location;
@CsvBindByName(column = "Phone", required = true)

private String phone;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}

public void setLocation(String location) {
    this.location = location;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}
}
```

Class for fix header order:

```
public class PersonMappingStrategy<T> extends ColumnPositionMappingStrategy<T> {

private static final String[] HEADER = new String[] { "Name", "Age", "Location", "Phone" };

@Override
public String[] generateHeader() {
    return HEADER;
}

}
```

Main worker:

public class ExcelWriter {

```
public static final String CSV_TO_READ_PATH = "path_to_my_csv.csv";
public static final String[] HEADER_MAPPING = { "Name", "Age", "Location", "Phone" };

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, CsvDataTypeMismatchException, CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException {
    String[] header =
        getRowsFromFile(CSV_TO_READ_PATH);
    List<String> headersFromFile = Lists.newArrayList(header);

    BufferedReader reader =
        Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(CSV_TO_READ_PATH));

    CsvToBean<Person> csvToBean = new CsvToBeanBuilder(reader)
        .withType(Person.class)
        .withIgnoreLeadingWhiteSpace(true)
        .build();

    List<Person> personList = csvToBean.parse();

    if (!isHeadersInProperPosition(headersFromFile)) {
        write(personList);
    }
}

private static void write(List<Person> persons) throws CsvDataTypeMismatchException, CsvRequiredFieldEmptyException {
    Writer writer = null;
    try {
        writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("convertedCSV.csv"));
        ColumnPositionMappingStrategy strategy = new PersonMappingStrategy();
        strategy.setColumnMapping(HEADER_MAPPING);
        strategy.setType(Person.class);

        StatefulBeanToCsv beanToCsv = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder(writer)
            .withQuotechar(CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
            .withMappingStrategy(strategy)
            .build();

        beanToCsv.write(persons);

        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static String[] getRowsFromFile(String filePath) {
    try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(filePath))) {
        return reader.readNext();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}

private static boolean isHeadersInProperPosition(List<String> headerFromDemoCsv) {
    return Arrays.asList(HEADER_MAPPING).equals(headerFromDemoCsv);
}

}
```